# How to make a DB call with an array of ids and get the first row of every of those ids?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, laravel, laravel-5

I have a php(laravel) code that i try to improve. Right now there are 50 DB calls but i figured out that it's probably possible to do this in 1 DB call but i'm not sure how though. I want to do the DB::Table('app_transaction_infos') query with the array of id's ($loaded_app_ids) and get as a result the first where('app_id', $loaded_app_id) for every id. After that i will run the loop on in, instead of looping the query over and over again. Now i'm not sure though how to write that query for an array as i described.

```
    foreach($loaded_app_ids as $loaded_app_id){
        if(empty($app_users_30d[$loaded_app_id])){
            // Create array with the app id to show it had 0 data in the last 30 days
            $app_users_30d[$loaded_app_id] = [];

            // Check if any history data of this app is available
            $appTransactionInfo = DB::Table('app_transaction_infos')->where('app_id', $loaded_app_id)->first();
            // If no data at all imported, set to no data
            if(empty($appTransactionInfo)) {
                $nodata[$loaded_app_id] = 'nodata';
            }
            else{
                $nodata[$loaded_app_id] = 'hasdata';
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't know laravel but the `WHERE IN (x,y,z)`  so implode the array.

Comment: With that i get only 1 ->first result. I need 1 ->first result for each ID in the array.

Comment: Maybe `first()` only gives you the fist one?  Again I don't use laravel.

Comment: @AbraCadaver Yes, thats what i want. But the first of every id. My array has 50 ids. I want the first row of every id.

Comment: The ids are not unique?  That's bad bad.

Comment: No these ids are related to an product and i want the first row of every product. An product can have multiple rows though. So instead of 50x1000 rows i want 50x1 ( the first) row.

Comment: Maybe `group by` or `distinct` not sure but how do you determine fist?  The first one returned is arbitrary and differs unless you sort them on something.

Comment: group by without first was what i was looking for combined with the where in. Thank you!